# How to filter Azure CLI outputs by value using JMESPath queries on Bash when keys contain hyphens/dashes?

Tags: bash, azure-cli, jmespath

The `az keyvault secret list --vault-name "lofa"` results in a list similar to what is below (but has way more elements of each type):

```
[
  {
    "attributes": { ... },
    "id": "https://lofa.vault.azure.net/secrets/conn-string",
    "tags": {
      "file-encoding": "utf-8"
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": { ... },
    "id": "https://lofa.vault.azure.net/secrets/a-password",
    "tags": null
  },
  {
    "attributes": { ... },
    "id": "https://lofa.vault.azure.net/secrets/another-password",
    "tags": {
      "testThis": "miez",
      "what": "else"
    }
  }
]
```

Tried to filter the "easy" targets first (i.e., JSON objects where the keys contain no hyphens), and it worked as expected:

```
$ az keyvault secret list --vault-name "lofa" --query "[? tags.testThis=='vmi']"
```

The same didn't work for `file-encoding` keys (resulting in `invalid jmespath_type value`):

```
$ az keyvault secret list --vault-name "lofa" --query "[?tags.file-encoding=='utf-8']"
```

So tried single quotes next, but no joy:

```
$ az keyvault secret list --vault-name "lofa" --query "[?tags.'file-encoding'=='utf-8']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you do want a solution that does not forces you to escape any quotes, you can use:

- simple quotes for your shell script parameters

  ```sh
  az keyvault secret list --vault-name 'lofa' --query '[]'
  ```
- double quotes for your key, since it contains a dash

  ```sh
  az keyvault secret list --vault-name 'lofa' --query '[?tags."file-encoding"]'
  ```
- [backticks for your literal](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions), `utf-8`

  ```sh
  az keyvault secret list --vault-name 'lofa' --query '[?tags."file-encoding"==`utf-8`]'
  ```

Comment: Wow, i'm such an idiot - why didn't I think of just simply start with single quotes?... On the other hand, I would've never thought of using backticks, at all. (Extra thanks for linking the part in the JMESPath spec for the explanation!)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was using

- **escaped double quotes** (`\"`) for JSON object **keys** (in this case, for `file-encoding`), and
- **single quotes** for JSON object **values** (in this case, for `utf-8`)

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name "lofa" --query "[?tags.\"file-encoding\"=='utf-8']"
```

---

NOTE: Not sure why this is, or what is happening exactly but when trying to substitute the single quotes with escaped double quotes as well for the value part,

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name "lofa" --query "[?tags.\"file-encoding\"==\"utf-8\"]"
```

it resulted in a list that had all the entries **except** the ones that had `tags.file-encoding`.